# Slow Assembly.LoadFrom but only once per day

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly

I have a very strange issue with `Assembly.LoadFrom` call. My application uses it intensively on startup to load ~ 500 assemblies. Usually it works OK and takes only ~50ms to load all of them.

But every morning the very first application launch spends ~15 seconds on that operation. Every single day the very first run is very slow because of that.

The call looks pretty simple:

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(path);
```

Probably the reason - Windows Defender. But I have no clue how to diagnose it further. Maybe anyone has ideas?

Comment: Is it HDD or SSD? Does it run immediately after booting? Are all of those immediately required from the first screen? A simple workaround is to mimic LibreOffice's quick start that merely preloads required files on boot, or just a batch/scheduled task to trigger Defender to scan those assemblies.

Comment: SSD (tested on 6 different machines already), it runs NOT after booting OS... And yes, we need to load them all to find components for a component container

Comment: But the idea about scheduled task on OS startup is cool =)